# how to build 2D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

i am creating a 2D array using java  but the problem that is it dont work as it should i am trying to build it using tow for LOOP.

can anyone help me to fix this error and explain how the 2D array works, because each website has it own way to create it and i want the right one using the for loop.

## this is my code:

```
package test5;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String output = "";
        int[][] matrix = new int[4][4];


        matrix[0][0] = 1;
        matrix[1][1] = 2;
        matrix[3][2] = 3;

        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            int[] sub = matrix[i];

            for(int j = 0; j< sub.length; j++){
                System.out.println(sub[j] + "");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

## this is the output

```
1
0
0
0

0
2
0
0

0
0
0
0

0
0
3
0
```

what i want is to get this output

```
1 0 0 0
0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 3 0
```

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: What's the issue? The output is exactly what you put into it. `explain how the 2D array works` just Google `java 2d array`, there's an ENORMOUS number of tutorials/examples on exactly this.

Comment: @javadev That's the exact same as the current output. Are you indicating a *formatting* issue or a *data* issue?

Comment: The method `println(...)` prints what you want then adds a new line character (aka printline). You probably meant to use `print`(...)` inside the inner for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting the output as a two by two matrix, then the code should be

```
System.out.print(sub[j] + "");
```

Use [`print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

If this is the output you want, `1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0`

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    int[] sub = matrix[i];

    for(int j = 0; j< sub.length; j++){
        System.out.print(sub[j] + "");
     }

}
```